# N-Body Simulation in a Seamlessly Repeating World

Tags: summation, vectors, simulation

For running an N-Body simulation it is required to calculate the force between every pair of massive bodies. The force applied on body $a$ from body $b$ is calculated as follows:
$$F_{ab} = -G\frac{m_am_b}{|r_{ab}|^2}\hat{r}_{ab}$$
Where $r$ is the vector from body $a$ to body $b$.

After summing the force of every body on the body $a$ we can calculate the velocity and update the location of body $a$ in space.

Now say we limit the 3D space inside a cube of width $w$, and make the world seamless so that every body that was at say $\begin{bmatrix}x_0\\y_0\\z_0\end{bmatrix}$ now repeats as follows:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_0+wi\\y_0+wj\\z_0+wk\end{bmatrix} \,;\, i,j,k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Now for calculating force of body $b$ on body $a$ we have the following formula:
$$\begin{align}
F_{ab} &= -\sum_{i=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}{G\frac{m_am_b}{|r_{ab}|^2}\hat{r}_{ab}}}}
\\\\
&= -Gm_am_b\sum_{i=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{\hat{r}_{ab}}{|r_{ab}|^2}}}}
\\\\
&= -Gm_am_b\sum_{i=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{r_{ab}}{|r_{ab}|^3}}}}
\\\\
&= -Gm_am_b\sum_{i=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{\begin{bmatrix}x_b-x_a+wi\\y_b-y_a+wj\\z_b-z_a+wk\end{bmatrix}}{\biggl((x_b-x_a+wi)^2+(y_b-y_a+wj)^2+(z_b-z_a+wk)^2\biggr)^{3/2}}}}}
\\\\
&= -Gm_am_b\sum_{i=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{\begin{bmatrix}\Delta{x}+wi\\\Delta{y}+wj\\\Delta{z}+wk\end{bmatrix}}{\biggl((\Delta{x}+wi)^2+(\Delta{y}+wj)^2+(\Delta{z}+wk)^2\biggr)^{3/2}}}}}
\end{align}$$

Now the questions are:

- Does such summation converge?
- Can this summation be simplified to a closed form formula?

Comment: Seems like an example of Olbers' paradox, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbers%27_paradox, also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeans_instability

Comment: Take a look at [Ewald summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ewald_summation)